# How to edit a html select element in Experience editor - MVC

Tags: experience-editor

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 with MVC, and want to know the correct way to make a `select` element editable in Experience editor.

Following the instructions [here](https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/how-to-use-editframe-in-sitecore-mvc/) -

created a custom button "Edit City" in core database, but it isn't showing up in Editor when this rendering is selected. The binding works fine in preview mode.

When the page is opened in Exp.Editor, there are 10 rows (I have 10 cities) under that dropdown, that say {"commands":[{"click::"chrome:common:edititem.....

Followed these steps to render the element.

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult RenderCitySelector()    
{    
  IEnumerable<Item> cities = ItemExtensions.GetDatasource().Children;
  return View("~/Views/cities.cshtml", cities);    
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

using (Html.BeginEditFrame(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource, 
"/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Custom Buttons/Edit City"))    
{    
  <select id="ddlCity">    
  @if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)    
  {    
    foreach (Item city in Model)    
    {    
      <option value="@Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Fields.CityCode, city)">
      @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Fields.CityName, city)
      </option>   
    }    
  }    
  else
  {    
   foreach (Item city in Model)
   {    
    <option value="@city.Fields[Templates.Fields.CityCode].Value">
    @city.Fields[Templates.Fields.Cityname].Value
    </option>
   }    
  }    
</select>    
}
```

Comment: following the link you provided, it is for editing the field from the current context datasource item. But in your case you are using children `IEnumerable<Item> cities = ItemExtensions.GetDatasource().Children;'`So, you need to use editframe inside the foreach loop setting the current child as DataSource.
`foreach (var childItem in Model.Children)
{
using (BeginEditFrame({Button Folder}, childItem.FullPath))
{
{Markup}
}
}` check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933167/sitecore-editframe)

Comment: Tried your suggestion. The custom button still doesn't show in the panel. Can I choose any button type like field edit/custom exp. etc or a certain one?

Answer (score 1):

This should go into comment, but cannot suggest code in comment, so writing as an answer

Could you try below?

```
@model IEnumerable<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>

@if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
{
    using (Html.BeginEditFrame(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource,
        "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Custom Buttons/Edit City"))
    {
        foreach (Item city in Model)
        {
           EditCity : @Html.Sitecore().Field(Templates.Fields.CityName, city)
        }
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (Item city in Model)
    {
        <select id="ddlCity">
            <option value="@city.Fields[Templates.Fields.CityCode].Value">
                @city.Fields[Templates.Fields.Cityname].Value
            </option>
            }

        </select>
    }
}
```

Comment: No change. Its the same